# PHP Generate Code to Textbox?

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to make something similar to http://webstarthelp.com/forwards.html | I've searched around but haven't really found any good examples.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't get what you mean. Is something wrong with using <textarea> and filling the content with echo?

Comment: Can you specify what you're trying to do exactly, or any code you've tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why dont u use jquery function `.val()` to change the value of the textbox?

http://api.jquery.com/val/

http://jsfiddle.net/wVUhN/1/

Answer (score 4):

"I haven't really found any good examples". Yet you just posted one....

Let's look at that page. You type something into the first box. Hit "Submit" and the second box is generated.

So "Submit" must be doing something useful here....

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="dHR(document.getElementById('file_url'), document.getElementById('Delay'))">
```

Interesting.... what's that `onclick` method for? Seems to call a function right? We should look up what `dHR()` is...

```
function dHR (HR_file_url, HR_Delay){
  HR_code.value= '<html><head>\n' +
  '<meta HTTP-EQUIV=\"Refresh\" CONTENT=\"' + HR_Delay.value + '; URL=' + HR_file_url.value + '\">\n' +
  '</head><body>\n' +
  'This page has been moved.<p>\n' +
  '<a href=\"' + HR_file_url.value + '\">IF YOU ARE NOT REDIRECTED, PLEASE CLICK HERE.</a>\n' +
  '</body></html>';
  return false;
}
```

Now for this I used `FireBug` in Firefox, but you can fetch that code simply by digging through the page source code to find a reference to `fwd.js`. More importantly, that function is extremely basic. It takes the input you provided and meshes it within a whole whack of static text.

**But what about PHP?**

Unfortunately PHP doesn't have dynamic operations on a page without using Javascript like this example. If you want similar functionality there really isn't any way to it unless you're willing to work with a page reload. In your case you'd have a form like this.

```
<form action="php_handling_page.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" name="file_name" />
 .....
</form>
```

I'll let you fill in the blanks. But what it does is calls `php_handling_page.php` when you submit the form. That page is then loaded in which you can gather the parameters passed to it.

```
<?php
$file_name = $_POST['file_name'];
....
?>
```

Using that, you have a variable, `$file_name` that you can then use to construct a textbox or string.

```
<?php
echo "This is a bunch of static text, that leads the variable with a value of " . $file_name . " and then is followed by more static text!";
?>
```

Questions?